# Java (Spring Boot) - IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

We have a rather complex Spring Boot project and it works fine on Windows during development. However when we run the project on Ubuntu we get a bizzare exception

```
LOGBACK: No context given for c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@310623126
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.8.RELEASE)
2020-07-08 12:56:42.860  INFO 6 --- [           main] redacted.Application            : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on c72273bf4d02 with PID 6 (/home/plugin/app.jar started by root in /home/plugin)
2020-07-08 12:56:42.867  INFO 6 --- [           main] redacted.Application            : The following profiles are active: default
2020-07-08 12:56:44.745  INFO 6 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-07-08 12:56:45.119  INFO 6 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 345ms. Found 13 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-08 12:56:46.089 ERROR 6 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:423) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:257) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:291) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at redacted.Application.main(Application.java:61) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [redacted-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [redacted-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [redacted-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [redacted-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:571) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1307) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1195) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Executors.java:89) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at redacted.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:43) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 39 common frames omitted
```

On Ubuntu we are using OpenJDK 11. It works on Windows with the same JDK, but it doesn't on Ubuntu. We also tried to run the project in a new Windows Sandbox instance and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot : Unable to load cache item: javax/servlet/Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296264/spring-boot-unable-to-load-cache-item-javax-servlet-filter)

Comment: Please remove `spring-core` maven dependency and try.

Comment: @Amitkumar we don't have that dependency. We use Spring Boot.

Comment: @silentsudo no. The exception stack trace is different from ours. Also we don't have the `spring-core` dependency in our `pom.xml` since it comes from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` dependency.

Comment: @BoškoBezik : Could you please share your `pom.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by trying to create a thread pool with **0** threads. We have a development VPS with **1** thread and we had a line of code like this:

```
public static final Executor EXECUTOR = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1);
```

This caused the exception. In hindsight the exception stack trace gave us an obvious clue at the bottom

```
at redacted.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:43)
```

It literally pointed to the exact line that faulted.

Another thing you should definitely do is update the apt-cache with `sudo apt-get update` command install the latest OpenJDK verison.

Answer (score 3):

Check the Java version, I had the same error when I tried to run a project developed in Java 11 with Java 17.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure, but i think the problem caused by `spring-core` dependency. Can you try to remove `spring-core` dependency from pom.xml file and try to run it again.

Comment: That wasn't the solution for our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To address the InaccessibleObjectException, you can add JVM options directly in IntelliJ IDEA to open up the necessary modules:

Go to Run > Edit Configurations....

Find your application's run configuration.

In the VM options field, add the necessary --add-opens option, for example:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```